# Divs over a three js animation scrolling down on desktop but not on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, three.js

I have a Three js animation in the document body:

```
container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
```

And two divs layered on top set with:

```
#holder {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sitearea {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #sitearea {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The animation is interactive:

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
```

On desktop the animation responds to mouse movement and on mobile it responds to touch.

Its possible to scroll the holder div down on desktop and bring up more text while the background animation stays in place.

But the holder div is not touch responsive on mobile and therefore can not slide up any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these functions:

```
function onDocumentTouchStart() {
  var theholder = document.getElementById("holder");
  theholder.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
}

function onDocumentTouchMove() {
  var theholder = document.getElementById("holder");
  theholder.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
}
```